# Apache 2 RewriteRule getting wrong capture group

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting trouble with capture groups in a rewrite rule. Here is a sample:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.php$ test.php?captureGroup=$1
```

The capture group I'm getting is "test" instead of what I typed in the address bar. Strangely this works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.php$ test.php?captureGroup=$1
```

i.e a url like "88.php" gives me "88" as capture group. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your target URI (`test.php`) is also matching `[a-z]+.php` pattern and rule is executing twice.

You can use this to prevent that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z00-9]+)\.php$ test.php?captureGroup=$1
```